# Change letters for day name

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, date-time

When I use this code the name of the day been writed with a small letter.

```
get_the_time(strtotime($DateValue)), 
get_the_time('l d.m.Y H:i', $post)
```

I want the name of the day looking like this:   **Monday, Sunday, Thursday** etc.
Now it look like this  **monday, sunday**

What do I do wrong ?

Comment: Your code is fine - are you sure you aren't changing it via CSS on display?

Comment: I don`t think so.
Maybe it has to do with the language to do.
When I use Wordpress in english then the day name has big first letter, but when I use Norwegian wordpress language, then the first letter has change.

Any idea ?

Comment: A quick Google search reveals that day names are not capitalized in Norwegian.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, @vancoder points out that it appears day names are not capitalized in Norwegian. If you *require* that they be capitalized, you could do something like this:

```
ucfirst( get_the_date( 'l', $post ) ) . 
get_the_date( ' d.m.Y', $post ) . 
get_the_time( ' H:i', $post );
```

...using PHP's [`ucfirst()`](https://www.php.net/ucfirst) to force the first character to be uppercased.

(I've also split the date and time to use [`get_the_date()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/) and [`get_the_time()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_time/), since it seemed semantically cleaner to me that way.)

Comment: Thanks that works fine.
One more question.
The dayname and date is on the same line, and the clock is showing on the line below.

I want it to show like this:   Thursday 07.04.2022  19:52

Comment: Nothing in my code forces a line break, so it might be a line-length thing in your site.